# jQuery get specific option tag selected values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this,

```
<select id="customUser_id" name="customUser_id">
  <option value="2" label="Friends Of Friends">Friends Of Friends</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="3" label="Friends Only">Friends Only</option>
  <option value="4" label="Specific People">Specific People</option>
  <option value="0" label="Only Me">Only Me</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the value of `Selected Option` using jQuery.

Currently I am using `onchange()` event like this,

```
$('#customUser_id').change(function(){
    if(($(this).val()==2)){
        $("#customWallPost3").text("Only Friends of Friends can see this");
    }
    else if(($(this).val()==3)){
        $("#customWallPost3").text("Only Friends can see this");
    }
    else if(($(this).val()==4)){
        $("#customWallPost3").text("Only the people above can see this");
    }
    else if(($(this).val()==0)){
        $("#customWallPost3").text("Only I can see this");
    }
    else{
        $("#customWallPost3").text("");
    }
});
```

this is only working when change the option value, but I also want to get selected option value with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried: $('#customUser_id').val();

Comment: Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SHPZE/

Comment: @Meherzad its not working :(

Comment: On the button click your got the selectd value in the select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what your are asking for...

> I also want to get selected option value with this..

but to get the selected option value, you use

```
  $('#customUser_id').val();
```

this gives you the selected value of the `<select>` with id as `customUser_id`

**UPDATED**

if you want to get the text of selected option then you can do

```
 $("#customUser_id option:selected").text();
```

Comment: selected value means <option selected="selected" value="3">Friends Only</option>

Comment: selected attribute value i want to get

Comment: value of default selected option

Comment: u mean u need to get the `Friends Only` and not `3` in `<option selected="selected" value="3">Friends Only</option>` ??

Answer (score 1):

Unsure with your question as 
`$('#customUser_id').val()` gives the value which is selected.

Still if you wish, with this you can iterate through each of the options and you can get the element with `selected` attribute

```
$('#customUser_id').children().each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('selected')) {
        // here you have the element with _selected_ attribute
    }
});
```

If you wish you can directly get the `attribute` which is selected

```
var selectedElt = $('#customUser_id').children('[selected=selected]');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create it in a more friendly way - using an array and a function:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ixevij/12/edit)**</kbd>

```
var arr_Infos = [
  'Only I can see this',                    // option value 0
  '',                                       // option value 1
  'Only Friends of Friends can see this',   // option value 2
  'Only Friends can see this',              // option value 3
  'Only the people above can see this'      // option value 4 (don't use comma)
];


function popoulateInfo(){
   var sel =  $('#customUser_id').find(":selected").val();
   $('#customWallPost3').text( arr_Infos[ sel ] ); 
}
popoulateInfo();             // run immediately

$('#customUser_id').on('change', function(){   
  popoulateInfo();           // run on change
});
```

Comment: yeah, you can see, default option is Friends only, but that text "Only Friends can see this" not displayed

Comment: great but when I click on `Only me`, text not displayed

Comment: @SumitBijvani you see the array with texts ? the retrieved value you used 0, 2, 3, 4, 5 are the arr_Infos array indexes. If you want the text `only I can see this` be the value `0` than just remove it from array 5 and put into array `0` position. Seems logic. http://jsbin.com/ixevij/7/edit

Comment: @SumitBijvani the code I posted was working fine 1h ago, just I was messing in the demos. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get value of selected value:

```
$('#customUser_id').val();
```

Here is the docs http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

You mean if you want the selected option to display - "Only I can see this" or "Only friends can see this" etc.... on load,
You can add this code with `.ready()` instead on `.change()`

```
$('#customUser_id').ready(function(){
if(($(this).val()==2)){
    $("#customWallPost3").text("Only Friends of Friends can see this");
}
else if(($(this).val()==3)){
    $("#customWallPost3").text("Only Friends can see this");
}
else if(($(this).val()==4)){
    $("#customWallPost3").text("Only the people above can see this");
}
else if(($(this).val()==0)){
    $("#customWallPost3").text("Only I can see this");
}
else{
    $("#customWallPost3").text("");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use trigger

```
$('#customUser_id').change(function(){
    // your code
}).trigger('change');
```